# Proving efficiency of GLS over OLS

Tags: least-squares, generalized-least-squares, efficiency

I'm trying to prove that GLS is more efficient than OLS.
I found out it is, I need to show that:

$\text{Var}^{-1}({\beta}_{GLS})-\text{Var}^{-1}(\beta_{OLS})$ is the positive semi-definite matrix, then GLS is more efficient than OLS. But I found difficult to show the answer the PSD.

More specific is show this relationship is PSD:
$\text{Var}^{-1}({\beta}_{GLS})-\text{Var}^{-1}(\beta_{OLS})=X^T\Omega^{-1}X-X^TX(X^T\Omega X)^{-1}X^TX$.

Hope anyone will help.

Comment: Keep in mind that GLS is more efficient than OLS if (1) the errors are correlated, and (2) the covariance matrix is known. If the covariance matrix is not known, which is almost always the case in practice, you have to estimate it and are then left with FGLS and FGLS is only asymptotically more efficient than OLS.